# WKWebView evaluateJavaScript is not working for youtube embedded video url

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, youtube, wkwebview

I've loaded a youtube embedded video to WKWebView:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/amtuB-2wGeQ?playsinline=1&autoplay=1

Then after WKWebView didFinishNavigation event is fired, I call:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('video').play()", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
    if let r = result {
        print(r)
    }
    if let e = error {
        print(e)
    }
  })
}
```

However, the javascript command is not being executed, both error and result are nil.

When I execute the same javascript command in Chrome developer tool, it successfully played the video and paused the video by calling "play()" and "pause()".

```
document.querySelector('video').play()
document.querySelector('video').pause()
```

I don't know what happened inside WKWebView, any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, finally figured out why it is not working.

If you are also struggling with "why my javascript is not working in WKWebView", below is a neat way to figure out why:

**1. Open Safari on your desktop, Preferences -> Advanced, enable "show developer menu in menu bar"**

**2. In the Safari menu, Develop -> simulator, connect your iPhone simulator**

**3. Now you can see the web page html and script in Safari, in the console input area, try run different javascript to see which one works.**

**4. Then call the one that works from "evaluateJavaScript"**

The reason why it didn't work from my case is that the embedded web page was rendered differently between common web browser and WKWebView. I took the browser script as example which didn't work.

With the help of Safari debugger, you can see what's really going on inside WKWebView, which is really cool.

Hope it helps if you ever run into the same problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use UIWebView instead of WKWebView and use this code for play youtube video.

```
#pragma mark - Embed Video

- (UIWebView *)embedVideoYoutubeWithURL:(NSString *)urlString andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *videoID = [self extractYoutubeVideoID:urlString];

    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoID, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

    return videoWebView;
}

/**
 @see https://devforums.apple.com/message/705665#705665
 extractYoutubeVideoID: works for the following URL formats:

 www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID
 www.youtube.com?v=VIDEOID
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHsHKzYOV2E&feature=youtu.be
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHsHKzYOV2E
 youtu.be/KFPtWedl7wg_U923
 www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=WHsHKzYOV2E#t=31s
 youtube.googleapis.com/v/WHsHKzYOV2E
*/

- (NSString *)extractYoutubeVideoID:(NSString *)urlYoutube {
    NSString *regexString = @"(?<=v(=|/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(?<=youtu.be/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)";
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:urlYoutube options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [urlYoutube length])];

    if(!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [urlYoutube substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];

        return substringForFirstMatch;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

or use google's youtube-ios-player-helper pod

Comment: I can't... my project has fixed to use only wkwebview... thanks though